Is this claim justified at the 99% confidence interval?

A sample of 200 bees from a colony is tested and 40 bees are found to
be infected. The colony of bees will collapse and not survive if 35%
or more are infected. Why it is possible at the 99% confidence level,
that the colony of bees might collapse?

My textbook answer is as follows

Since the confidence intervals intersect from 0.263 to 0.273, at the
99% confidence level it is possible that more than 35% of bees in the
colony are infected, and so it might collapse.

However, I am having trouble understanding this solution and cannot find any answers anywhere. If we calculate a confidence interval at the 99% level, for our observation of 40 bees infected from 200 bees, we get 0.127, 0.273. This is telling us that we can be 99% confident that the true proportion lies between 0.127 and 0.273.
What the answer has done however, is to assume the true proportion to be 0.35 and determine a confidence interval at the 99% level and show that these intervals overlap. However, this doesn't make any logical sense to me. Just because these two intervals overlap doesn't mean anything at all, because we are always 99% confident that the true proportion lies between 0.127 and 0.273 from our observation.
I suppose testing only gives probabilities and not certainties so it is still possible the colony collapses by chance, but I cannot see how it has anything to do with an overlap between confidence intervals. Could someone please give a clear solution to the problem?

Which textbook?

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Your confusion is justified.
The $99\%$ (Wald) CI for the observed sample is $(0.127145, 0.272855)$.  The book seems to incorrectly think that there is uncertainty about the $35\%$ value, as if this critical threshold for the percentage of infected bees that would lead to collapse, is derived from an experimental sample, which it is clearly not.  The only sample we have is the $X = 40$ infected bees out of $n = 200$ sampled.  In turn, we are using this sample to perform a statistical inference about the true proportion of bees in the sampled colony that are infected.  Under the assumption that the sampling was performed at random, then the binomial model is appropriate, and the resulting interval estimate characterizes the extent of uncertainty of the estimate for a given level of confidence.
Equivalently, you may use the exact statistic $X$ of the random number of infected bees in a sample of $n = 200$:
$$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 200, p)$$
where $p$ is the unknown parameter of interest.  Under the assumption that $p = 0.35$, the minimum threshold of the proportion of infected bees in order for the colony to collapse, the probability of having observed $X = 40$ infected bees or fewer, is
$$\Pr[X \le 40 \mid p = 0.35] = \sum_{x=0}^{40} \binom{200}{x} (0.35)^x (1 - 0.35)^{200 - x} = 2.51469 \times 10^{-6},$$
which is approximately $1$ in $397664$.  This is a tiny chance, meaning that the probability that we could have observed as extreme an outcome, were the colony truly at risk, is negligible, hence we can be quite confident, easily more than $99\%$ confident, that the colony is not at risk of collapse.
